# Find a specific object inside the array of objects from a ReferenceMany field

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I cannot find in doctrine manual how to do a very simple query. I don't know how to manage the equivalent of SQL "JOIN ..." with MongoDb.

```
abstract class Topic
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;
}

abstract class Message
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Date
     */
    protected $date;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Topic")
     */
    protected $topic;
}

abstract class User
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Message")
     */
    protected $messages;
}
```

I have a User id and a Topic id.
I want :
1) Find the most recent message from the user
2) Find the most recent message about the topic from the user

$dm->find('User', $id)->getMessages() gives me a "PersistentCollection"
$dm->find('User', $id)->getMessages()->getValues() gives me the array of the messages, but then I have to use PHP loops, i'm sure there is a way to create a query to do that ...

Am I supposed to use map or reduce ?

Can someone help me ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll have to fix your database schema:

A Message can belong to more than one User?

Usually a Message can have only an author, so I'll change the Message Document to store the author `User id`:

```
class Message
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="User")
     */
     protected $author;

     //Othe methods...
}
```

---

**Then to find the most recent Message from user:**

```
class User {

     /**
     * @ReferenceOne(
     *      targetDocument="Message",
     *      mappedBy="author",
     *      sort={"date"="desc"}
     * )
     */
     protected $lastMessage;

     //Other methods...
}
```

---

**And to find the most recent message about a topic:**

```
class User {

     /**
     * @ReferenceOne(
     *      targetDocument="Message",
     *      mappedBy="author",
     *      criteria={"topic" : "sport"}
     *      sort={"date"="desc"}
     * )
     */
     protected $lastMessageAboutSport

     //Other methods...
}
```

More info on: [Doctrine ODM Complex References Guide](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/complex-references.html)

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea that heavy annotations were the answer.